# How to install succesfully libsodium (for php7.2) on Centos7?

Tags: php-7.2, libsodium

I take a Magento project and when i run x debug I have an exception because libsodium is not installed then I went to install libsodium.
I then follow this tutorial https://lukasmestan.com/install-libsodium-extension-in-php7/ (because I have php 7.2 as it is a Magento project) and ... it didn't work out :(
When I do :

```sh
sudo pecl install -f libsodium
```

I have the problem :

> checking for libsodium... configure: error: Please install libsodium 
>   ERROR: `/var/tmp/libsodium/configure --with-php-config=/bin/php-config' failed

Do someone had the same problem ? I mean installing libsodium is what I want to do and for do that I need to install libsodium XD
If someone have a solution I would really be glad.
PS: in case of minus please let me know why so that I can improve my post

Comment: I am not sure about Centos but I use PHP 7.3 with Debian 10. Try installing PHP 7.3 on Centos.

Comment: @SaudIqbal unfortunalty I need libsodium for a Magento product which need php 7.1 (because Magento need my_crypr php library which is deleted from php 7.2 as far as I read in doc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok the solution was simple instead of looking on internet with useless installation process simply do :

```sh
 sudo yum --enablerepo=remi-php72 install php-sodium
```

Comment: I recommend to enable the repo permanently, as it provides only PHP, which will avoid more issues with future extensions. See the wizard: https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/

Answer (score 2):

For **CentOS: 8, PHP 7.3** to install php-sodium, use:

```
dnf install php-sodium
```

Comment: Won't work, since it is not part of CentOS repos! you must be using some third party repos like remi

Answer (score 0):

1. First check if it's enabled or not.

> **php -i | grep sodium**

2. If It returns nothing then run the following commands-

> **sudo yum install libsodium libsodium-devel**

> **sudo pecl install libsodium**

Then it told 'You should add "extension=sodium.so" to php.ini'.

3. Open **php.ini** file and under "Dynamic Extensions" add

> **extension=sodium**

Follow the **step-1** it should return -

```
sodium
sodium support => enabled
...
```

**DONE!** :)